# Is it right to point out rude language or just silently edit it?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

If you consider verbage in a question rude, is it best to point it out the user so they don't keep committing the same mistakes, or is it best to just silently edit the question? I've run into this question and mistakenly created some "wars" a couple times, but this wasn't my intent. I just don't like to keep seeing the same things over and over.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance-on-so

Comment: Not talking about that phrase itself, but just in general what the appropriate protocol is.

Comment: I think it does shed some light on this question, though. What if one person considers language rude but another believes it is the only polite way to ask? Who's to say which one is correct? Can they both be correct?

Comment: Your question assumes you must do one or the other. That is what moderator flags are for.

Comment: Ironic everyone agrees with me in the general sense, but in the specific sense I get stigmatized as a spammer.

Comment: If you weren't outright wrong in the text of your comments and edit reason, I doubt we'd even be discussing this.

Comment: Again, the problem is not that you made an edit or a comment, it's that you got into an edit war and a comment battle with the other person. Put differently, you got in a fight, and that's not okay.

Comment: I am (ugh) quite familiar with the situation, so to be fair - There was no "edit war" involving Greg, it was another user being immature. A picture is worth a thousand words, so [here's the rev history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6698785/revisions) (I believe this is the post in question, could be mistaken or there are more). The problem was Greg *accusing* users of "extreme rude/offensive language" by saying "Thanks in advance", which is of course absurd at best. OP has taken it out of context in this post, but surely this is what is really in question here.

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to make a judgement call based on the context. If it *appears* to be a one-time lapse in judgment — as best as we can predict these things — I would probably just edit it silently as a way to improve the content overall.

But two other scenarios come to mind — A well-meaning user might simply be accustomed to bad habits they picked up on other forums where rudeness is more prevalent. It might be beneficial to point out the behavior to help them realize the norms of the site. **But, for a "first offense," your goal is to *inform*, not to accuse or confront.**

Second situation where a comment may be beneficial — If you're seeing a common, bad behavior which is becoming increasingly common on the site, you can use the occasion to leave a public comment for the purpose of pointing out the issue. People will imitate what they see and sometimes it is beneficial to bring the issue to light rather than letting the problem grow under its own momentum.

If it's an on-going situation that continues unabated, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

If you feel the language is clearly meant to be offensive, edit it out, and flag it appropriately. If you do this consistently, over time you will see your flag weight go up - it means you are doing a good job. If over time you see it go down, it means you should use more caution when flagging and your flags will have less priority to the moderators who process them. The more your flags are deemed worthy, the louder your voice gets.

If it it's something debatable, or hard to tell if OP is intentionally being offensive, such as "URGENT PLZ HLP NAO!!!", you are probably going to be wasting moderators' time by flagging it. Just edit it out. Usually rude posts are pretty bad to begin with, so exercise your downvoting right while you're at it if the question sucks.

If you do see a pattern of rude or abusive behavior, over and over, it can be a good idea to make a note of it while flagging so that it doesn't persist. If you simply find that most Stack Overflow users are rude, I wouldn't let it get to you. Use the site for it's information and don't get caught up in the semantics.

Comment: This is what I have been doing! Thank you!

Comment: As below I ask: why is it necessary to *flag* when you can just edit out objectionable content yourself? Moderators don't need to process every instance of this. They only need to be called in when an edit war is on the verge of breaking out, i.e. if the original poster rolls back your edit. In that case, flag for moderator attention rather than making the same edit once again. Of course, I agree with the second and third paragraphs. Definitely if you see something becoming a *pattern*, then you should flag it for mod attention, including links substantiating your assertion of a pattern.

Comment: @CodyGray: I have seen answers and questions that were blatantly, intentionally, offensive or abusive, and deserved to be flagged as such. You get feedback on your profile about how the flag was dealt with, so this should be paid attention to closely to make sure you aren't wasting people's time.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the post to be less offensive, but fill in the ***Edit Summary*** with a gentle note:

- "Rephrased for clarity."
- "Mother{censored} is offensive to some."
- "Just the facts."
- "Removed emotional coloring."

etc.

No need to post a comment, and not always a need to flag.

(As you can tell, I was never much good at *easing* conflicts, {censored}s!)

Comment: The language in question was not offensive.

Comment: good idea to use the edit summary ...

Answer (score 2):

First, you should make sure the language in question is actually rude before going on a comment spree. Second, if it is extraneous text go and edit it out. If it is actually rude, edit it out and flag the question.

Being an English language pedant is *not constructive* on StackOverflow, especially when the phrase you're haggling over is demonstrably neutral at worst. StackOverflow is not English Language and Usage.

If you would like to haggle over English Language and Usage then please focus your commenting efforts on that community, where your comments have the potential to be constructive.

Otherwise, please contribute to the StackOverflow community with questions, answers, and comments that seek to improve the experience for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: I have tried to edit it out, seems to cause an edit war, see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6698785/revisions

Comment: Your edit reason is suspect at best, but your edit is spot on. I have no idea why Chris rolled that back, except perhaps your edit reason is incorrect. Otherwise it should have stayed as you edited it.

Answer (score -1):

If the language is obscene, flag it for moderator attention. If it is not worthwhile to flag it, then it is likely too subjective a language choice to really matter what you say, and editing a post for subjective rudeness is in itself rude in my opinion.

I would politely mention it to the poster, and let it be, unless it is so bad that it must be flagged. Anything else is too likely to get turned into a flame war on someones' part.

Comment: *"editing a post for rudeness is in itself rude in my opinion"* Why do you think that? This site is [collaboratively edited](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing), and removing or rewording something that people might find to be rude or offensive seems like a net positive change.

Comment: Correcting a mistake, making a question more universal, or editing for grammar and punctuation, sure. But if you start making subjective edits to other peoples' posts, you're balancing on a very thin wire. Edit a post because I've made a mistake, sure. But if you aren't willing to risk your rep points to point it out to a moderator, then it is your taste that is causing you to edit, and what makes your taste more valuable than his or hers? And if you edit for rudeness, and he reverts, and you edit... what then? That's why we have moderators.

Comment: It seems positive to you, and apparently to others. Keep in mind, I'm talking about point of view. Yours is one thing. The OP might have another. If something is rude to the point of needing to be changed, do it right. And risk your rep on being told you're wrong. I'm definitely not saying we should let vulgar behavior stand. Just that there is a system in place to deal with it already.

Comment: Pointing things out to a moderator, right or wrong, does *not* risk your reputation points. And why should you waste the time of our already-busy moderators with things you could just as easily change or improve yourself? Moderators should be left to deal with things that regular users *can't* handle (like if you edit and the original poster reverts; that's called an edit war, and *then* moderators need to step in). My theory is that the person who said whatever you think is rude didn't mean it that way, and aren't particularly attached to it. They won't mind if you fix it. I wouldn't.

Comment: And they might not. OR they might. Or they might not see it as rude at all. Or they might find you telling them what is rude, rude. I love that I'm being downvoted for telling you to follow the established system.

Comment: For a change, I didn't downvote this because I'm out of votes. But again the same: downvotes on Meta don't mean the same thing they do on the main site. Here, they indicate *disagreement*. It's all spelled out in the FAQ. More to the point, this is **not** the established system. It's a perfectly valid opinion, and I see your point, but as I mentioned above, moderator flags are generally intended for use in cases where the average user *can't* solve the problem. I already provided a link explaining that the Stack Exchange sites are collaboratively edited. *That's* the "established system".

Comment: Related: [Why edit out inflammatory language? Is that censorship?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77901/why-edit-out-inflammatory-language-is-that-censorship)

Comment: "Collaboratively edited" is intended to improve the content of questions and answers. Why do we have flags for moderator attention based on offensive or inappropriate comments? And why are they call moderators, if the point is not to provide moderation in disputes of this type? Your OP says that when you've done this, it turns in to a flame war. That was my original objection. Secondly, I had a mod on our site tell me that your flag weigh is affected by mods marking your flags valid or invalid. Not rep, but at least you risk something of your own when you tell someone they don't count.

Comment: The flags are for *comments*, which can't be edited. I thought we were talking about answers. And yes, they moderate *disputes*. Remember I said above that if an edit war were to break out (with the OP disagreeing with your edit and rolling it back), *then* you would need to call in a moderator. But there's no reason to get moderators involved in everyday usage of the site. I never said that it turns into a flame war to make edits, even over subjective things like language. I actually said I *welcom* it. And yes, it affects your flag weight. That counts for zilch. Totally meaningless. No risk.

Comment: Related post is referring to obvious and non-subjective comments, like cursing. Not to editing out something you feel is rude, but that you would have to explain to the poster why it was. If someone calls you an ass, edit out, by all means, That is not what I'm saying at all.

Comment: "I've run into this question and mistakenly created some "wars" a couple times, but this wasn't my intent". Sounds like you made an edit, and then had it turn into a war to me. More than once , too. Also, nowhere did you specify comments. And you can certainly flag a question or answer. Or did that flag link go missing?

Comment: Perhaps meaningless to you. Not to me. It is an indication of whether your decisions are trusted on the site. Just because they don't post it on your profile, it means nothing to you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not the person who asked the question... So I didn't say that. And the point was that question/answer flags do not include the option of "offensive" or "inappropriate" like comment flags do. There are about a *zillion* places where the moderators and everyone else try to tell you here that your flag weight is *meaningless* and that you shouldn't pay so much attention to it. It is not connected to your reputation. Yes, it means nothing to me.

Comment: Good for you. It's still rude to edit somebody else's content because you think it might maybe offend someone someday. And if someone does it to me, I'll revert it. Every time. I also do't go out of my way to be offensive, but the nature of disagreement is that someone usually finds something offensive. If I edit out things that offend me, I'd be deleting half your comments as supporting censorship. But I wouldn't even if I could, because it's ok to disagree.

Comment: All three answers above agree with what I'm saying. Why is it that my answer is different somehow? This is a serious question, not just a complaint, btw.

Comment: @zenbike: you should stop into [Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), or post a separate question if you're interested in discussing this at length. Editing - and attitudes toward editing - are a fundamental and critical part of the SE system, so it's important they're well-understood...